# Want to initialize a variable after a fetch function to later include in the Layout

Tags: javascript, html, variables, plotly

We have set a function named *processInput()* to return the sliders variable. This sliders variable must be reused after the *fetch function*. We also want to include the sliders variable inside the *Layout* variable to make a mesh network.

But we are having a problem retrieving the data from the processInput function and using it in the later part of the code. We are being unable to use both sliders and also the input that will be passed by the end-user. Please help us with the solution.

Here is the full code for our application:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>
            Visualization
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.58.5.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/file-saver@2.0.5/dist/FileSaver.min.js"></script>-->
        <style>
            #format-select,
            #download-btn{
                position: absolute;
                top: 25;
                left: 0;
            }
            #format-select {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50;
                left: 0;
            }

            #quantity {
              position: absolute;
              top: 75;
              left: 0;
            }

            #submit {
                position: absolute;
                top: 100;
                left: 0;
            }

            #quantity2 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 125;
                left: 0;
            }

            #submit2 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 150;
                left: 0;
            }
            
            .graph-container {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                height: 100vh;
                position: relative;
            }
            .main-panel {
                width: 100%;
                height: 800px;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }
            .side-panel {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: -300px;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            transition: right 0.5s;
            overflow-y: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            }
           
            .side-panel.open {
            right: 0;
            }

            .arrow {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20px;
            left: 20px;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-top: 20px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
            border-right: 20px solid #2196F3;
            cursor: pointer;
            }

            .arrow.open {
                transform: rotate(180deg);
            }


        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="graph-container">
            <div id="network" class="main-panel">
            </div>
            <div id="graph" class="side-panel">
                <div class="arrow"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <label for="quantity"> Enter the value </label>
        <input type="text" id="quantity" >
        <button id = "submit" onclick="processInput()">Submit</button>

        <label for="quantity"> Enter the value </label>
        <input type="text" id="quantity2" >
        <button id = "submit2" onclick="updateFont()">Submit</button>
        
        <!-- Buttons for downloading the graphs -->

        <label for="format-select">Format:</label>
        <select id="format-select">
            <option value="png">PNG</option>
            <option value="svg">SVG</option>
            <option value="jpeg">JPEG</option>
        </select>
        <button id="download-btn">Download</button>

        <div id="main">
            <!-- <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Open Sidebar</button>   -->
          </div>

        <script>
            // Function to make a variable and store the value through the input that we provide
            var fontSize;
            function updateFont(){
                var fontSize = document.getElementById("quantity2").value;
                //return fontSize;
                console.log(fontSize);
            }
            
            //var input;
            // Function to take the input and change the size of the arrows with the help of the slider

            function processInput(input, ncones) {
                //var input = Math.floor(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
                //var input = 42.5;
                //        
                console.log(input);
                

                var nscale = [input * 0.1, input, input * 10];
                var steps = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < nscale.length; i++) {
                    var visible = Array(ncones).fill(true); // all cones
                    // visible[0] = true; // set the 0th cone to be visible
                    var step = { method: "update", args: [{ visible: visible, sizeref: nscale[i] }], label: nscale[i] };
                    steps.push(step);
                }
            
                var sliders = {
                    x: 0.1,
                    y: 12.0,
                    len: 0.8,
                    pad: { t: 50 },
                    steps: steps,
                }
                console.log(sliders);
                console.log(nscale);
                console.log(steps);
                return sliders;
                
                //return input;
            }
            
            
            

            function openNav() {
                document.getElementById("graph").style.width = "500px";
                document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "500px";
            }
            function closeNav() {
                document.getElementById("graph").style.width = "0";
                document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
            }

            const sidepanel = document.querySelector('.side-panel');
            const arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');

            arrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
            sidepanel.classList.toggle('open');
            arrow.classList.toggle('open');
            });

            //read the data from the json file
            fetch("result_0.json")
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then( data => {
                    var ncones = data.ncones;
                    var x = data.x; 
                    const input = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
                    console.log(input);
                    sliders = processInput(input, ncones);
                    //Initializing array for storing the variables
                    

                    var layout = {
                      updatemenus: [
                        {
                          x: 1.5,
                          y: 15.5,
                          yanchor: "top",
                          xanchor: "left",
                          showactive: false,
                          direction: "Right",
                          height: 8000,
                          width: 8000,
                          buttons: [
                            {
                              method: "restyle",
                              
                              label: "Velocity"
                            },
                            {
                              method: "restyle",
                              
                              label: "Pressure"
                            },
                          ],
                        },

                      ],

                      scene: {
                          xaxis: { title: { text: "X Axis Label", font: { size: fontSize } } },
                          yaxis: { title: { text: "Y Axis Label", font: { size: fontSize } } },
                          zaxis: { title: { text: "Z Axis Label", font: { size: fontSize } } },
                      },
                     
                     sliders: [sliders], // add the slider to the layout
                    };

                    Plotly.newPlot('network', data, layout)
                    var formatSelect = document.getElementById('format-select');
                    var downloadBtn = document.getElementById('download-btn');
                    downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                      var format = formatSelect.value;
                      Plotly.toImage('network', {format: format, width: 800, height: 600})
                        .then(function(url) {
                          var link = document.createElement('a');
                          link.download = 'chart.' + format;
                          link.href = url;
                          link.click();
                        });
                    });
                    })
            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The JSON file that has been used:

```
{
    "ncones": 63,
    "x": [
        1011.06536865234,
        950.190307617188
    ]
}
```

Highlighted areas to look for :

After  tag go to processInput()

1. After  tag the processInput function has been defined
2. The initialization of sliders variable after the fetch function
3. Inclusion of sliders variable inside the Layout variable